# PubSubLite: Accessing PubSub Lite cross region

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsublite

Is it possible for the publisher /  subscriber to be in different region from the location of the Lite installation ? 
For example two use cases 
1. The publisher is in a GKE app in Europe but the Lite and its subscribers are in US
2. The publisher and the Lite are in the same region , say Europe but the subscriber is in US

Comment: Why to use a regional service if you need to globally access to it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for the publisher and subscriber to be in different regions from the location of the Lite installation, yes. There is a charge per GB for data transmitted from Europe to the US or vice-versa, per the [general network pricing guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing#general).